# Ansible : Loop over two register variables using with_items

Tags: ansible

I have stored checksum of local and remote files in two different variables. Now I want to compare those checksum and fail if they don't match. Below is code.

```
   - name: Get cksum some of files copied locally
     stat:
       path : "{{ item.src }}/{{ item.file }}"
       checksum_algorithm: sha1
     delegate_to: localhost
     with_items: "{{ files }}"
     register: local_files

   - name: Get cksum of remote files 
    stat:
      path : "{{ item.dest }}/{{ item.file }}_{{ item.package }}_NEW"
      checksum_algorithm: sha1
    with_items: "{{ files }}"
    register: remote_files

  - name : Compare local and remote cksums. Fail if not matched
    debug:
      msg="Checksum don't match"
    failed_when:  item[0].results.stat.checksum !=  item[1].results.stat.checksum
    with_items:
      - "{{ local_files.results }}"
      - "{{ remote_files.results }}"
```

When I run this, I get below error.

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'item[0].results.stat.checksum !=  item[1].results.stat.checksum' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item[0].results.stat.checksum !=  item[1].results.stat.checksum): dict object has no element 0"}
```

How can I correct it to compare checksum?

Comment: You already know `debug` module ー start with checking what `item[0]` and `item[1]` contain to see how far you are from what you imagined.

Comment: And this is way too broad for StackOverflow. Define your problem first: you have two lists of arrays, from which you need to extract some of the key-value pairs (because they contain more differing information than you want), and then to compare these two resulting lists - likely with set-theory filters. All this is already covered in separate questions on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
- name: Get cksum some of files copied locally
  stat:
    path : "{{ item.src }}/{{ item.file }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{ files }}"
  register: local_files

- name: Get cksum of remote files 
  stat:
    path : "{{ item.dest }}/{{ item.file }}"
  with_items: "{{ files }}"
  register: remote_files

- name: Compare local and remote cksums. Fail if not matched
  fail:
    msg: "Checksum don't match"
  when:  item[0].stat.checksum != item[1].stat.checksum
  with_together:
    - "{{ local_files.results }}"
    - "{{ remote_files.results }}"
```

Comment: Worked for me !